# Making a ListBox of Spreadsheet Headers

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to view some spreadsheet data in UiApp, and I've run into a simple problem that is above my pay grade.

I've opened the spreadsheet using a listbox and pulled the headers, and now want to display the spreadsheet headers in another list box.  When I do how I know to populate listboxes from array, it doesn't work and all the headers appear as one item.

Here's what the headers look like from the Log:

```
*[[Item Name, Item Sku/Model#, Main, Seler Logo, UPC, M.S.R.P., MAP Price, Website Customer Price, Amazon Competitive Situation, Ship Weight, FedEx Ground HD 06413 to 90210, Amazon Selling Price, Shipping Charge, Selling Price + Shipping Charge, Amazon Commission @ 15%, Product Cost, Shipping Cost FedEx Ground HD (FR. Col L), Profit, Margin %, Actual Weight, Length, Width, Height, Description/Copy, Technical Specs, Order Fullfilled by:, Shipment Within:, Stock Level, ]]*
```

I am adding them to the list box with this code:

```
var listbox = app.createListBox();
for(i in data){
listbox.addItem(data[i]);  
  }
```

I'm guessing it's the extra set of brackets, but I haven't had to strip anything off a data string before.  Little help?

Thanks,
Martin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed a 2D array, only the columns are of interest here since you took only one row, change like this :

```
var listbox = app.createListBox();
for(i in data[0]){
listbox.addItem(data[0][i]);  
  }
```

Comment: 2D arrays have made my brain painful for quite a while but the old gas forum brought me a lot of information and now it's clear as crystal ^^ I'll never thank those guys enough :-)  I'm sure they'll recognize themselves...